# Secure Gateway client not starting on Linux

Tags: security, client, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I have installed the Secure Gateway client (v1.4.2) on RHEL V7. When I attempt to start the client, I receive an error that log4js cannot be found. I am trying to find out where log4js should reside.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob3TQ.png)

Additional information:

Installation was done as follows:
rpm -ivhf ibm_securegateway_client_1.4.2_x86_64.rpm --force

Hardware: Intel (not AMD)

The installation log indicated that the install was successful.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you were doing? How did you install it? Are you working in the Bluemix environment?

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Please add --force option on Redhat Version 7.

rpm -ivhf --force ibm-securegateway-client-1.4.2+client_amd64.rpm

Comment: I did the installation on Intel (not AMD) hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your node modules did not install correctly.  Please ensure you have the correct permissions and reinstall so the node modules can be correctly added.

On a side note, you may encounter issues when attempting to start the client from outside the client directory due to how it searches for the associated files.

Comment: Thank you.   Can you direct to instructions for installing node modules?

Comment: You can go to the client folder and run `npm install` which should pull all the dependencies from the package.json file.  Ideally, this should have been handled during installation, but seems that wasn't the case this time.